# Usando append pero requiero reemplazar por otro dato jquery

Tags: jquery, lista

Poseo un codigo para obtener datos dentro de un modal.

dichos datos los recupero en mis input sin ningun problema usando el siguiente fragmento de codigo

```
$('#id').val(datos['id']);
$('#user').val(datos['user']);
$('#operador').val(datos['operador']);
```

Pero dentro de mi modal tengo un `div` que recupera el contenido de algunos datos

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div id="text_id">ID: </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div id="text_user">Usuario: </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="user" name="user">
</div>
```

Esos datos los recupero usando:

```
  $('#text_id').append(datos['id']);
  $('#text_user').append(datos['user']);
```

Pero cuando voy a modificar otro dato entonces se van agregando mas y mas datos mostrados en mi `<div>` he intentado usando algo como `replaceWith()` pero no logro hacerlo funcionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso bastaría con reemplazar append por html y hacer una pequeña modificación, ya que append

> https://api.jquery.com/append/

inserta contenido al div y al usar html lo reemplazarías en lugar de agregar más contenido:

```
$('#text_id').html("ID: " + datos['id']);
$('#text_user').html("Usuario: " + datos['user']);
```